# Using Choice Data Type in Validation Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, choice-field, syntax

I am working on a validation to determine if a selected choice is okay based off a previous selected choice.

There are a number of categories (labeled 1 thru 13). Category #1 and Category #13 can have Type N selected. The other categories (2-12) can have any type (N, S, V, O).

Both the Category and Type are Choice columns.

Current formula:

```
=AND(OR([Category]=#1,[Category]=#13),[Platform Type]=N)
```

Q1: Can I even use a choice column data type in the validation formula?

Q2: If so, what syntax is incorrect in my formula that is preventing it from saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your formula into this:

```
=AND(OR([Category]="#1",[Category]="#13"),[Type]="N")
```

And to answer your additional questions:

1. You can use choice columns in the validation formula
2. You should just enclose the values you are comparing with in the double
   quotes.

Comment: I tried your suggested change and did not receive a syntax error, however, I received the following error `One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.`

Comment: Please try using the different name for the Type column (and update the formula accordingly).

Comment: @cheshire Do you actually have a column named "Type". That's not a legal name. You should have seen this when you attempted to create the column: "The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved. Choose another name."

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP My column is actually 'Platform Type', I should've realized this is an important distinction. Sorry, was trying to keep the info as generic and unidentifiable as possible. Will update question.